# failed test classes wont be included in code coverage

Tags: apex, unit-test, deployment, failing-tests

I want to know if some of the test classes fails in production then they will included in code coverage or not?.

in production org i m getting 74% code coverage. I am unable to deloy a class.
can you please suggest me any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any Apex class which has written `@isTest` annotation at the top is not count against Apex code coverage. But if any test method is failing, all code which was covered by those methods will uncovered and lead to low coverage.

To solve the coverage issue:

- Identfy all test classes which have coverage less than 75% or failing.
- Move them into sandbox if they are not in sandbox or have old code
- Increase their code coverage in sandbox
- Include them in Changeset alon with components which you are trying to deploy.

It would work for you.